# Totals in order email template

Tags: orders, email-templates, totals

Please help me to find where i can edit the totals from order email template. I attached an image with what i want exactly.

*the language from picture is romanian but you understand what i mean.

Thanks in advanced.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Update Model method

   - Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

     ```
     function sendNewOrderEmail()
     {
         array(
             'order'         => $this,
             'total' => $this->getGrandTotal(),
         ) 
     }
     ```
   - Then add in template simply

     ```
     {{var total}}
     ```
2. You can directly manipulate the template variable

   ```
   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml
   ```

Comment: Using this {{var total}},only price is showing,but price with proper format is not showing like $3499.00.  @Abhishek Gupta.

Comment: This sendNewOrderEmail() method is not found in order.php. I am using Magento-2.2.7.

Comment: please guide me @Abhishek Gupta .